# How can I prevent command substitution from removing NUL and trailing newline(s)?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

[An Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607352/) says that command substitution removes NUL 
 and trailing newline(s), and provides the following commands to prevent it from doing so,

```
FILE="$(mktemp)"
printf "a\0\n" > "$FILE"
S="$(uuencode -m "$FILE" /dev/stdout)"
uudecode -o /dev/stdout <(printf "$S") | od -tx1
rm "$FILE"
```

`cat "$FILE"` doesn't remove NUL or trailing newlines. Can it replace

```
S="$(uuencode -m "$FILE" /dev/stdout)"
uudecode -o /dev/stdout <(printf "$S")
```

so that the suggested commands can be simplified to

```
FILE="$(mktemp)"
printf "a\0\n" > "$FILE"
cat "$FILE" | od -tx1
rm "$FILE"
```

?

Comment: `cat "$FILE"` doesn't remove NUL or trailing newlines, but `$(cat "$FILE")` would.

Comment: I updated. I am not planning to use `cat "$FILE"` in a command substitution, and does it work now?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder what it is you're trying to do with the command substitution and the NULs in the end. Perhaps it would be possible to give better answers if the big picture was visible.

Comment: @ilkkachu nothing in particular.  Just wondering why the author used uuencode and uudecode instead of cat?

Comment: @Ben - the SO answer you referenced provides the explanation. Bash variables  (`S` in that example) cannot contain null bytes so `uuencode` is needed to encode that null byte to something else

Comment: @Ben, ah, right. I tried to answer that question below.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing about the linked question is in the title: "How to read a file **into a variable** in shell?" The answer is that you don't, not in Bash, since Bash can't handle the NUL bytes.

This can be worked around somewhat by encoding the file so that the literal NULs are represented some other way. That could be Base64 encoding (as `uuencode -m` does), or URL encoding, or whatever. That's what the answer there does, it encodes the file using `uuencode` to a "nicer" string with no NULs, then stores that in the variable `S`. (A plain `S=$(cat file)` would not work, it would try to store the file unchanged, with the NUL bytes and all.) The opposite action of decoding the file is also shown.

Usually, there's not much need for that, and one should probably try to avoid doing that. It's easier to process files by keeping them as files and processing them with external tools as necessary. But the question there was specifically about how to store a file (an arbitrary file) in a shell variable. In theory, there just might be some use for that. Maybe.

---

Though in your case, if you just want to print some fixed string, then `printf "a\0\n" > $filename` or similar works just fine since any byte can be represented with the `\NNN` escapes.

Comment: Thanks. I figure out what I want now. I want to perform substitution using parameter expansion `echo -n "${string//"$pattern"/"$replacement"}"`, and assume it is impossible to do it other way. The value of `string` can only come from a file, but I don't know how to store the file content into the variable `string`: `string="$(cat "$inputfile")" ` will remove NUL and trailing newline(s). What would you do?

Comment: In `S="$(uuencode -m "$FILE" /dev/stdout)"`, is there some case where `$S` is useful?

Comment: @Ben, if you have a file with possible NULs, and you want to perform substitutions on it, use `sed` (or `tr`, or Perl, or maybe even `awk`, depending on what exactly you want to do). Base64 encoded data is really hard to process since you have the original bytes smashed into characters in groups. Some other sort of encoding would lend itself better for processing in the shell, but still, just use the tools made for the purpose...